# FirebaseDatabase web iOS / OSX

Tags: ios, macos, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on a website for a school project containing a button which you need to press. When pressed, the button takes a value from the database, child 'aantal' and adds 1. When that is done, it re-uploads it back to the database. One page further, you can see the live number of that child. The problem is, this is not working on iOS 9 or lower and on OSX Yosemite or lower. On android and windows it works fine.

Reusable code;

This is just a button. If you press the button it adds 1 on the int. This is very strange because it doesn't doesn't work on the OS mentioned above.

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.6.9/firebase.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript">
        // Initialize Firebase
        var config = {
            apiKey: //API KEY,
            authDomain: //FIRBASE DOMAIN,
            databaseURL: //DATABASE URL,
            storageBucket: //STORAGE BUCKET,
            messagingSenderId: //MESGSENDID
        };
        firebase.initializeApp(config);
        var number;
        var database = firebase.database().ref().child('aantal');
        function buy() {
            database.on('value', snap => number = snap.val());
            var count = parseInt(number, 10) + 1;
            database.set(count);
        }
    </script>
```

This code will not work, initialise own Firebase project for testing. 
For security reasons I removed my details.

Comment: Exactly what doesn't work? And I'm guessing the problem is with certain versions of Safari rather than with a version of iOS?

Comment: Nothing works. The browser doesn't add 1 and it doesn't display the number from the database. Is there a workaround for the safari bug?

Comment: You're not using Safari in private browsing mode, right?

Comment: No i'm not. I even checked safari's settings to see if JavaScript was enabeled.

Comment: You should look transactions. You will get current user, increment it and save. And with completion block you can redirect. I used firebase with swift so i cannot provide sample code.

Comment: @MaartenWeyns Can you create a jsbin that reproduces the problem on the Safari/OSX combination that you describe, but that works elsewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**
Turns out Safari (9.1/iOS 9.3 and below) doesn't support arrow functions.

Changing `database.on('value', snap => number = snap.val());` to `database.on('value', function(snap) { number = snap.val()});` fixed the issue.

Well I mean, that code shouldn't work anywhere.

```
function buy() {
    database.on('value', snap => number = snap.val());
    var count = parseInt(number, 10) + 1;
    database.set(count);
}
```

Firebase is asynchronous, and you're not waiting for it to actually load number from the database.

This should work.

```
function buy() {
    database.on('value', snap => {
      number = snap.val();
      var count = parseInt(number, 10) + 1;
      database.set(count);
    });
}
```

I don't know whether this is actually the issue you're having or if you just wrote this in your example. Also, when incrementing values you should be using Transactions.

```
function buy() {
    database.transaction(function(value) {
        if (value) {
            value++;
        }
        return value;
    });
}
```

Comment: I tried this code, but this still doesn't work in safari. It does in chrome tho, like my original code..

Comment: How are you testing this? On actual devices? It's working fine for me on an iOS 8.4 simulator.

Comment: Yes i tested this code on macbook OSX el capitan in safari

Comment: Give me a couple, I'll go get my sister's macbook, should be a pretty low version as well.

Comment: Thank you. Altough el capitan is not particulary low.. Shouldn't it be able to handle it?

Comment: Tested it on OSX Yosemite with Safari 8.0.8 and it worked fine. I'm starting to think it's more of a local issue with your system? And yes, it should definitely be able to handle it, I'm running El Capitan as well, and it's working fine here.

Comment: Weird.. I tested it on a macbook, iPhone and iPad and none worked.. Did you test in safari and what Firebase sdk are you using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137824/discussion-between-pieter-laebens-and-maarten-weyns).